# Difference between page and image request

Tags: php, request, phantomjs, httprequest

My basic question is do browsers handle these two requests differently?

`<a href='imageGenerator.php?id=1'>Browser Request</a>`

vs

`<img src='imageGenerator.php?id=1' />`

Both generate an image stream on-the-fly (unless the file already exists). However, the image request will timeout rapidly before completing the image generation sporadically via `<img>` tag, while the other request will not. See code below:

```
public function generateThumbnail($url) {
    ignore_user_abort(true);
    set_time_limit(0);
    // [...]
    $pub_path = public_path() . "/{$pathToFile}";

    if (!\File::exists($pub_path)) {
        // PhantomJS to screen cap
        $screenCapture = new Capture($url);            
        $screenCapture->save($pub_path);
    }

    return response()->file($pub_path);
}
```

Code has been shortened for brevity, but the question remains, shouldn't both requests be treated relatively the same?

Comment: You can do a test yourself. Create a test site and use both (in separate sessions) to get an image. During testing, you should run Wireshark to capture all packets. You will probably see some differences in HTTP headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that it had to do with Laravel throwing an error when it couldn't read the env file on occasion.